# APScheduler: How to stop a job which has not finished after a certain time?

Tags: python, apscheduler

My main script looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":       

    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

    scheduler.add_job(job_x,'cron',id="job_x",day_of_week="tue", hour=11, minute=49,
    jobstore="default")        
    scheduler.add_listener(my_listener,EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("Exception Caught")
```

Is there a way to check whether the job 'job_x' is taking more than 1 week to run, and if so, to stop it?

I was also wondering if background scheduler wouldn't be a better option.